# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at (URL)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

i have web application with multi layer (Business Layer,Data Access Layer ,Service Layer and Ui Layer) 
i call service layer (web api) in Ui Layer Razor pages(Using JQuery And Ajax )
as

```
<button id="btn">ddd</button>

script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var filmtable = $("#DataTableHtmlId");
        $('#btn').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: 'https://localhost:11111/api/film/1',
                withCredentials: true,
                AccessControlAllowCredentials: true,

                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {

                    alert("err");
                }
        });
        });

    } );
</script>
```

when call controller that fire the view that have last ajax calling
Error This Appear
[image]

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:11111/api/film/1. (Reason:
>   CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).[Learn More]
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://localhost:11111/api/film/1. (Reason:
>   CORS request did not succeed).

After Search i found many solution 
as Registering  **Cors** In **ConfigureServices** as

```
            //Cors policy is added to controllers via [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
            //or .UseCors("CorsPolicy") globally
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

and Apply CORS In **Configure** as

```
        //Apply CORS.
         app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
         app.UseHttpsRedirection();
         app.UseAuthentication();
         app.UseMvc();
```

But error Also Appear Any help?

Comment: Can you inform if app.UseCors("CorsPolicy") is been called before any defined endpoint (before calling UseMvc()). "CORS Middleware must precede any defined endpoint". And can you verify (using fiddle our F12) if you server response is providing "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header when you make the request? Regards.

Comment: i know this Issue 
           app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
I Updated Question with adding the order of using

Comment: Are you sure the asynchronous ajax request is working? I've made the experience, that sometimes I get this Cross-Origin Request error although there is a problem with the async call. Do you find any error under network tab in developer tools of your browser?

Comment: Where did you add `Cors` configuration? You need to add it to api project instead of ui project.

Comment: @Tao Zhou Thank You I Added It To ui project.  change it And put it in api it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution From Comment

Enable `CORS` Configuration in api project instead of ui project.